# Bootstrap-vue file-form looks like plain text

Tags: forms, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to use b-file-form from bootstrap-vue [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-file/).

I've used vue-cli to create bootstrap-vue template project. And I
've tried to create file-form in my component. But file-form looks like plain text without css. Meanwhile file-form works as it should.
BootstrapVue has registered in vue app.
[image]

What can be wrong? And what I can to do to fix that?

Comment: Any evidence that the bootstrap css is being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was decided after update bootstrap-vue to 2.0.0-rc.1